# Multiclass ROC curves in R

Tags: r, machine-learning, artificial-intelligence, classification

I'm new to the concept of **ROC curves**. I've tried to understand it by reading a few tutorials on the web. I found a really good example [here](http://scikit-learn.org/0.10/auto_examples/plot_roc.html) in python which was helpful.

I want to plot a **ROC curve** for **multiclass** classifier that I built(in Python). However, Most of the solutions on the web are for **2 class problems** and **not multiclass**.

However, I finally found "[multiclass.roc](http://xavier.robin.name/blog/2011/01/21/proc-1.4-released)" function in **pROC** package in **R** which does multiclass ROC curve plotting.

The following is a simple example:

```
library(pROC)
data(aSAH)
multiclass.roc(aSAH$gos6, aSAH$s100b)
```

However, I don't understand how to **interpret** it (as I don't know R).

Can anyone please point out what **aSAH$s100b** variable refers to? I can say *aSAH$gos6* points to different classes of data in **aSAH** dataset.

Comment: look at `?multiclass.roc` for how the function works. `?'$'` for what the `$` syntax means. `aSAH` is a `data.frame`, so have a look at `?data.frame`

Comment: Watch the first few of these R tutorial videos: `http://www.twotorials.com/`. That will let you understand the basics of what's happening there.

Comment: Hi @garak, I know this is an old question, but for completeness, I added a follow-up answer with 3 minimal reproducible examples explaining the necessary objects required by `pROC::multiclass.roc()`. I hope it could help future users.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Additionally, you might want to look at [Fawcett, 2006](http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/j.patrec.2005.10.010) for a very nice guide to understanding and implementing ROC plots.  He also addresses multi-class ROC and AUC, as well as points to additional resources.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question but for completeness, and for future visitors I will add a brief list of examples using the `pROC::multiclass.roc()` function. When it comes to the software requirements, the only one is to make sure that the names of the columns of the predictions matrix match the true classes (`real_values`).

The first example generates random predictions. The second one generates a better prediction. The third one generates the perfect prediction (i.e. always assigning the highest probability to the true class.)

I printed `head(obj)` the results, therefore no need for R understanding is required to follow up the examples.

Technical details of the computations used by `pROC::multiclass.roc()` can be found at [Hand & Till (2001)](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1023/A:1010920819831): *A simple generalization of the area under the ROC curve for multiple class classification problems. Machine learning, 45(2), 171-186.*

```
library(pROC)
set.seed(42)
head(real_values)
real_values <- matrix( c("class1", "class2", "class3"), nc=1 )

# [,1]    
# [1,] "class1"
# [2,] "class2"
# [3,] "class3"
############################
#### Random predictions ####
############################
random_preds <- matrix(rbeta(3*3,2,2), nc=3)
random_preds <- sweep(random_preds, 1, rowSums(a1), FUN="/")
colnames(random_preds) <- c("class1", "class2", "class3")


head(random_preds)

#       class1    class2    class3
# [1,] 0.3437916 0.6129104 0.4733117
# [2,] 0.6016169 0.4700832 0.9364681
# [3,] 0.6741742 0.8677781 0.4823129

multiclass.roc(real_values, random_preds)
#Multi-class area under the curve: 0.1667

############################
#### Better Predictions ####
############################

better_preds <- matrix(c(0.75,0.15,0.5,
                         0.15,0.5,0.75,
                         0.15,0.75,0.5), nc=3)
colnames(better_preds) <- c("class1", "class2", "class3")

head(better_preds)

#       class1 class2 class3
# [1,]   0.75   0.15   0.15
# [2,]   0.15   0.50   0.75
# [3,]   0.50   0.75   0.50

multiclass.roc(real_values, better_preds)
#Multi-class area under the curve: 0.6667


#############################
#### Perfect Predictions ####
#############################
perfect_preds <- matrix(c(0.75,0.15,0.5,
                          0.15,0.75,0.5,
                          0.15,0.5,0.75), nc=3)
colnames(perfect_preds) <- c("class1", "class2", "class3")
head(perfect_preds)

multiclass.roc(real_values, perfect_preds)
#Multi-class area under the curve: 1
```